# Chown and the risk of corrupting the backup disk

Tags: bash, bsd, acl

I am about to modify the file ownership recursively in a filesystem that uses ACLs. Because it is my backup disk, I thought I'd solicit comments on the script before I run it.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Replace Foobar, Bob, and Brand.
PREFIX="/Volumes/Foobar-Time-Machine/Backups.backupdb/Bob’s MacBook"
SUFFIX="/Brand/Users/"
USER="bob"

for dir in "${PREFIX}"/*/
do
    chmod -R -a "group:everyone deny chown" "${PREFIX}${dir}${SUFFIX}${USER}"
    chown -R $USER "${PREFIX}${dir}${SUFFIX}${USER}"
    chmod -R =a# 1 "group:everyone deny add_file,delete,add_subdirectory,delete_child,writeattr,writeextattr,chown" "${PREFIX}${dir}${SUFFIX}${USER}"
done
```

Do you spot a disaster waiting to happen? The first chmod is meant to remove minimal ACL and the second is meant to restore it. Can the script be made safer? Needless to say, the script would be run as sudo.

Comment: For readability, consider changing `$PREFIX$dir$SUFFIX$USER` to `${PREFIX}${dir}${SUFFIX}${USER}`.  Rewrite it to use ksh, or bash, and you'll be better off (read http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/CshTop10.txt for more info).  Other than that, you seem to only be chowning backups for `bob` to `bob`, and denying the everyone group access to those files.  I don't see any problems with that, as those files would be owned by `bob` on a restore anyways.

Comment: Done. Thanks. The problem is not so much who owns the files after a restore (I'm comfortable with chwon-ing on my working drive). The problem is that the history is invisible (through ownership protection). Changing ownership on the backup drive takes the risk of corrupting the format used and making the backups unusable.

Answer (score -1):

I would use find with '-print0' and xargs... ACL are cryptic, better not to use them.

Comment: Cryptic or not, ACLs must be tackled, with find-to-xargs or directly.

Comment: You shouldn't make a statement such as "don't use ACLs" without offering an alternative. Standard UNIX permissions are not a valid alternative.

Comment: They are valid in 99%, just more work with groups.